# Remove the white text shadow from disabled links in IE8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, extjs, css

We are using Ext JS for an application in work, building a custom theme for it. We currently have a dark colour scheme including menus with dark backgrounds. In some of the menus some of the links are disabled at certain points, which all perfectly. However IE8 seems to add a sort of white text shadow, which I am sure is normally fine but as the text is light grey and the background is dark grey the white text shadow makes it look blurry and even makes the other enabled links more disabled as they look darker.

Does anyone know of a way to remove the text shadow (I realise it is not css text-shadow as IE does not support it).

Comment: could you supply a small screenshot?

Comment: nevermind. There's no way to get IE to change the style of disabled items so the best way is JEBR0's solution. Mimic it being disabled by deactivating the click-function and setting the cursor to 'default'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to accomplish this would be to set a class and just mimic it being disabled.

```
<a href="#" class="disabled">&nbsp;</a>
```

And then jquery to disable their behavior.

```
$(function ()
{
    $("a.disabled").click(function ()
    {
    return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks Jannis and JEBR0. We are using ExtJS to create the links and control their enabled/disabled status, Ext doesn't put the disabled attribute in most browsers as it is not standard so it must be already doing something similar to JEBR0s suggestion somewhere. It is just adding the attribute in IE which is the only browser that does this weird styling, which is very frustrating. We may have to overwrite some Ext behaviour or replace the way all our menus work with a custom function as JEBR0 suggested.